# Race to decide the rank

Tags: algorithm, math, comparison

N people participate in a race consist of many rounds.
In a round, M people could race. We only record their rank and do not record their score. 
What is the minimum number of rounds we need to determine the K fastest people?
It seems a classic problem. If you know, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Could you define the question more thoroughly? What are the conditions for determining contestants in subsequent rounds, for example?

Comment: Yes, it's a classic problem around here to ask other people to do your homework.

Comment: If M equals 2, you have a simple sorting algorithm. The rest (M>2) is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Do you need to know the order among those K people?

Comment: @Filburt could you give me some references, thank you~~

Comment: @svick Yes, we need to know the order.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But we do not need to know the order of all the N people. We only need to know the first K.

Comment: @Xophmeister How to arrange the rounds depends on your choice.

Comment: @Filburt Why all you think it from homework? It seems classic for you for that you are an expert, but maybe not for more beginners. Please be kind to them. Thanks~~

Comment: @Kun It is expected that you show what you have tried yourself to solve the problem. It is considered bad to just ask for a solution. Puzzle questions (code golf, etc.) along the lines "I know the solution - guess what it is" are not too welcome also. If you show you are working on the problem and can tell us where you got stuck people will jump in and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `R*` denote the optimal value of R, the number of rounds used.  It's easy to show that if `N=K*M` and `M=K*K` then `R* = K+1`.  Example:  `K=7, M=49, N=341`: Run `K=7` rounds with non-overlapping groups. `K` is the smallest number of rounds that can touch every item, but that number of rounds cannot prove, for any given item, that it is or isn't in the top K.  Hence `R* > K` for the `N=K^3` and `M=K^2` case. Now run one more round with the top 7 items from each of the previous rounds and select the top 7 from this round.

I'm not aware of the stated question as a "classic problem" and think my example illustrates that the problem is distinct from sorting-type O(n ln n) complexity problems, and is more aligned with [median or tournament algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_algorithm#Lower_bounds) or [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm).  There is, of course, a large literature for pooled testing and weighing algorithms, and some of the reasoning used in solving those problems applies here, but their specific methods do not.

Comment: that's just a special (trivial) corner-case